# How to cast List<<MyClass> to List<T>?

Tags: kotlin

I tried to return a specific list from generic method

code bellow:

```
val list: List<Animal> = listOf(Animal(1), Animal(2), Animal(7))

val storage = object : Storage  {
    override fun <T> fetch(clazz: Class<T>): List<T> {
       if(clazz is Animal::class.java){
           return list
       }
        throw RuntimeException()
    }

}
```

But I have an exception:

```
Error:(14, 20) Kotlin: Type mismatch: inferred type is kotlin.collections.List<polar.QueryTest.Animal> but kotlin.collections.List<T> was expected
```

How to return list correctly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The compiler cannot figure out the relation between the types `List<T>` and `List<Animal>` in your example, so you should make an unchecked cast with the [`as` operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html#unsafe-cast-operator). Also note that you're using the [`is` operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html#is-and-is-operators) where you probably meant to use a simple equality check:

```
val list: List<Animal> = listOf(Animal(1), Animal(2), Animal(7))

val storage = object : Storage {
    fun <T> fetch(clazz: Class<T>): List<T> {
        if (clazz == Animal::class.java) {
            return list as List<T>
        }
        throw RuntimeException()
    }
}
```

If the unchecked cast warning disturbs you, you can suppress it with the following annotation: `@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")`